# Firebase social login - verify email

Tags: angularjs, spring, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm currently using Firebase as auth system in my application based on AngularJS and Spring as backend server. My app requires registration system, but no user should be able to register by himself. Only admins can add new users. I also want to make use of Firebase Social Login.

I'm using a custom auth system provided by Firebase (see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/create-custom-tokens).
Everything is working well when I'm using login and password authentication. Before generating custom auth token, I'm able to check if user exists in my database.

My aim is to add social login based on custom authentication. After user authenticates with a social provider using Firebase, I want to check if email returned is in my database.

I can imagine the situation when social provider returns JWT token with claims that contains email, I send it from front-end to my backend server and verify if the token is correct and if the user exists in my database. If true, backend generates custom Firebase auth token and sends it to front-end.

It is possible using Firebase? Maybe I can achieve it other way?